# Activiti - HistoricTaskInstanceQuery, search by property of variable which is JPA entity

Tags: java, activiti

I have a task with variable which is JPA entity.

What the HistoricTaskInstanceQuery API provides is only search by the entity itself:

```
query.processVariableValueEquals("entity", entity);
```

My goal is to search by the entity attributes, something like (pseudo code):

```
query.processVariableAttributeEquals("entity", "entity.subEntity.name", name)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I found similar question with no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363739/complex-activiti-jpa-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way out of the box to do this.
Options to consider:

1. Post processing of result set using something like an iterator to generate the list of entity id's and then use a custom query against the entity tables. This is rather agricultural but is likely your fastest route.
2. Create your own custom MyBatis query using the approach described here: https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#advanced.custom.sql.queries
   and here: http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2014/01/17/execute-custom-sql-in-activiti/

Option 2 is probably the best option for you but is a little more work.

Greg